# Is it possible not to show keyboard when deleting filter text from SearchView?

Tags: android, search, searchview

I am using standart SearchView in action bar. Is it possible not to show keyboard when I delete text from SearchView with closed keyboard?

Comment: How are you deleting text without keyboard?!!